# Mikrotik API reference for `passthrough=no`

Tags: networking, router, wifi, mikrotik

In several parts of the [Mikrotik API Manual](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:IP) there are references to the `passthrough=no` and `passthrough=yes`.

e.g.,:
[Manual: Transparent Traffic Shaper](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/TransparentTrafficShaper)
[Manual: "/ ip firewall mangle"](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:IP/Firewall/Mangle)

But nowhere have I seen a complete description of what this attribute *does*! Can someone link to documentation or give a complete description of the behavior of this attribute?

(Please note that I am **NOT** referring to the similarly named action: `action=passthrough`.)

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, when you use `passthrough=yes`, for example in a mangle rule, then the packet if it gets matched by that rule it's processed by the subsequent rules.

Where in case you use `passthrough=no`, if the packet gets matched by that rule, it will not get processed by the subsequent rules which can be useful to save some CPU as stated at the bottom of the manual page you posted.

There are certain types of configurations that `passthrough=yes` is needed, but in most cases I believe that it's safe to use `passthrough=no` unless you need otherwise.

Comment: In the older 2.9 version of the Documentation there is a reference to the passthrough option. http://www.mikrotik.com/testdocs/ros/2.9/ip/mangle.php
passthrough (yes | no; default: yes) - whether to let the packet to pass further (like action passthrough) after marking it with a given mark (property only valid if action is mark packet, connection or routing mark)